# Hide help in suite bar

Tags: 2016

in SharePoint 2016, i would like to hide the help button **?** from suite bar.

[image]

How I can do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use CSS as the following :

```
<style>
#O365_MainLink_Help
{
display:none;
}
</style>
```

**if you have a publishing site, try the following**

- Create a new CSS file, add the above code > upload it to style library.
- Go to site setting > Look and Feel > Master Page >

[image]

- At Site Master Page Settings > Scroll down till `Alternate CSS URL`
- Check `Specify a CSS file to be used by this site and all sites that inherit from it:`
- Browse to your CSS file
- Check  `Reset all subsites to inherit this alternate CSS URL`  if you need to apply CSS for all subsites.

[image]

**if you don't have a publishing site,**

- Take a copy from your current master page.
- Edit the current master page.
- Paste the above code in head section.
- Save and publish the master page as a major version.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, where I can use that code ?!!

Comment: are you have a publishing site?

Comment: yes i am using a publish site

Comment: I have updated my answer , please check it , hope it help you :)